# AspNet Core ignore virtual directory path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a hybrid web application that has WordPress as the root site with an aspnet core web application as a virtual directory. The IIS structure looks something like:

```
+- DefaultWebSite (hosts WordPress)
|    +- web (virtual direcotry that hosts the aspnet core site)
```

Within the aspnet core site, when I redirect to a page or use tag helpers the url includes "/web/blahblah" which makes sense. However, I don't want that. How do I force the aspnet core site to ignore the virtual directory path and generate urls like "/blahblah" without web?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the routing middleware in such a way that it knows where the controller name comes in the URL.

For Ex. if your asp.net core root url is  - http : // www.mysite.com / web

You can configure routing like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default_route",
    template: "/web/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: That appears to be happening automatically now. But I don't want "/web/" in the address at all.